DBT Post_hook execution
I'm encountering an issue with a macro in dbt that is meant to check if a table exists before executing a conditional delete. The macro looks like this:
{% macro check_table_exists(project, staging_schema, dmt_table, audit_table) %}
  {%- set sql_query = "SELECT * FROM " ~ project ~ "." ~ staging_schema ~ ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='" ~ dmt_table ~ "'" -%}
  {%- set result = dbt_utils.get_single_value(sql_query) -%}
  {{ log("result: " ~ result, info=true) }}
  {{ log(result is not none, info=true) }}

  {% if result is not none %}
    DELETE FROM {{ project ~ '.' ~ staging_schema ~ '.' ~ dmt_table }}
    WHERE date_extraction IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT date_extraction FROM {{ project ~ '.' ~ staging_schema ~ '.' ~ audit_table }}
    )
  {% else %}
    SELECT 1
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

The macro is invoked in the following way:
{% set table_exists = true %}
{% set project = env_var('GCP_PROJECT_APP') %}
{% set staging_schema = 'MP0_travel_exp' %}
{% set audit_table = 'audit_dmt_fact_HotelLocFee_t' %}
{% set dmt_table = 'dmt_fact_HotelLocFee_t' %}

{{ config(
    post_hook=[check_table_exists(project, staging_schema, dmt_table, audit_table)]
) }}

Issue: The check_table_exists macro always defaults to the else block, even when the table exists. Upon debugging, I found that the result variable first returns None and then later receives the table name. It seems that the post-hook executes with None, causing the macro to default to else and skip the intended DELETE operation.
Is there a way to ensure that result correctly holds the table name from the start, or to delay the execution of the post_hook until the correct value is available? Any guidance on how to manage this behavior in dbt would be greatly appreciated.
this is an exemple of Output with log :
13:37:28  Registered adapter: bigquery=1.8.2
13:37:29  result: None
13:37:29  False
13:37:29  result: None
13:37:29  False
13:37:29  [WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
There are 1 unused configuration paths:
- models.mobi_pilot.MP0_exp.compliance
13:37:29  Found 70 models, 2 seeds, 54 data tests, 47 sources, 613 macros
13:37:29  
13:37:31  Concurrency: 16 threads (target='dev')
13:37:31  
13:37:31  1 of 1 START sql table model MP0_travel_exp.audit_dmt_fact_HotelLocFee_t ....... [RUN]
13:37:32  result: fco-data-sg-mobipilot-dev
13:37:32  True
13:37:37  1 of 1 OK created sql table model MP0_travel_exp.audit_dmt_fact_HotelLocFee_t .. [CREATE TABLE (3.8k rows, 907.0 KiB processed) in 5.81s]
13:37:37  
13:37:37  Finished running 1 table model in 0 hours 0 minutes and 7.28 seconds (7.28s).
13:37:37  
13:37:37  Completed successfully
13:37:37  
13:37:37  Done. PASS=1 WARN=0 ERROR=0 SKIP=0 TOTAL=1

FYI : I used different solutions for table verif such as adapter.get_relation
Thank you!

But it looks like it is working. At the beginning you get None because it is compilation only, and if you look at https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/get_single_value.sql it returns None when execute is false. Then you can see in your log "result: fco-data-sg-mobipilot-dev" | "True" between "1 of 1" and "1 of 1", so how can you tell it is not working? Have you checked your query history?

simply because if it works the running query must be this 'DELETE FROM {{ project ~ '.' ~ staging_schema ~ '.' ~ dmt_table }}
WHERE date_extraction IN (
SELECT DISTINCT date_extraction FROM {{ project ~ '.' ~ staging_schema ~ '.' ~ audit_table }}
)'
but when looking at the logs the one that runs it's SELECT 1

This could be because information_schema is a metastore and if your post_hook is meant to run just after the dbt model which created this dmt_table , then there might be some latency to it in information_schema.Having said that I looked at he documentation of information_schema but I could not find any information about latency of it.
As a workaround you could directly use the DELETE statement on the table and if the table does not exists it would throw an error which could be handled like shown in this answer
{% set delete_query %}
      -- your delete statement
    {% endset %}

    {% set result = run_query(delete_query) %}

    {% if not execute %}
      SELECT 'Error executing delete query for {{ dmt_table }}' AS errormsg
    {% endif %}

